# Check if number is made of both 0 and 1 using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have just started with regex. I am unable to make an expression to check if number contains only 1 and 0 and nothing else.
In python

```
re.match("[01]", b)
```

This matches for either 0 or 1 I think.

What will be the expression to check that the string contains all the elements of a given set and nothing else.

Comment: The current answers all mention the `+` quantifier which requires one or more matches. If you want to allow zero or more matches then use the `*` quantifier.

Comment: The title is well written and states "both 0 and 1".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add anchors and a quantifier:

```
re.match("^[01]+$", b)
```

Now the expression only matches a string if it consists of 1 or more characters, each either `0` or `1`. The `^` start and `$` end strings ensure that only whole lines can be matched.

`+` is a quantifier, it means that the preceding element (the `[01]` character class) needs to match at least once. This means empty strings don't match either.

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match("^[01]+$", '011001')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10a06c5e0>
>>> re.match("^[01]+$", '0110012') is None
True
>>> re.match("^[01]+$", '') is None
True
```

Online demo at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/jG7tA3/1).

However, if your input string must contain *at least both a `0` and a `1`*, you could use sets:

```
b and set(b) == {'0', '1'}
```

This will test for a non-empty value `b` that consists entirely of `0` and `1` characters, and *both have to be present*.

You can do this with a regular expression still, using a look-ahead expression:

```
re.match(r'^(?=.*1)[01]+$', b)
```

Here, `(?=.*1)` only matches, if there is at least 1 `1` character in the text that follows, but won't directly match the text.

Online demo at [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/jR8rS4/2).

The regular expression is a lot faster:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> import re
>>> def nonzero_binary_set(b):
...     return b and set(b) == {'0', '1'}
... 
>>> def nonzero_binary_re(b):
...     return re.match(r'^(?=.*1)[01]+$', b) is not None
... 
>>> tests = ['', '00101011001110', '000000000000', '1111111111111',
... '10100011010101' * 1000, '0' * 10000]
>>> timeit.timeit('map(f, tests)', 'from __main__ import tests, nonzero_binary_set as f', number=10000)
3.7346549034118652
>>> timeit.timeit('map(f, tests)', 'from __main__ import tests, nonzero_binary_re as f', number=10000)
0.8998291492462158
```

Comment: The regex term is 'quantifier' and last time I checked, 'at least once' means one or more, so... it's kind of redundant to use 'at least once, or more' =P. Just nitpicking there.

Comment: @Jerry: I didn't mean to imply you were, sorry about that!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for nice example of measuring timing. Anyway, the strings you are evaluating are in last 2 cases very long. If you would use **shorter strings** `tests ['', '0010101', '000000', '111111']` the **timing gets better for using set**. `nonzero_binary_set => 0.0381159782409668` versus `nonzero_binary_re => 0.08502388000488281`

Comment: @MartijnPieters assuming that input is really a string (even empty one), the test `b and set(b) == {"0", "1"}` can be shortened to `set(b) == {"0", "1"}`. Interesting thing is, your test (if `b` is not empty) speeds up processing empty strings. In other situations it slows it down a bit.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky: Those differences are very small though, and the function stack push and pop may actually play a disproportionally larger role in that time. That's why you use larger inputs, to magnify the differences. You are right that the `b and ` portion is redundant here, a holdover of the `b and set(b) <= {'0', '1'}` variant (allowing for `'11111'` and `'0000'` as valid inputs).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `^[01]+$`

Explanation:

`^` is the start of the string
`$` is the end of the string
`+` means match one or more, in this case one or more of `[01]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
re.match("^[01]+$", b)
```

`^` - matches the beginning of the string

`[01]` - matches a `0` or a `1`

`+` - means one or more of the previous character (one or more `[01]`)

`$` - matches the end of the string

---

You can read more about regular expressions in python [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 2):

In case, you would accept other than regexp based solution, then following test could work for you:

```
>>> set("011010")
{"0", "1"}
```

Making a set from a string takes the string as iterable, where each item is a character.

Set picks just one representant of each unique value found in the iterable.

With another string:

```
>>> set("0110310")
{"0", "1", "3"}
```

So the test looks like:

```
>>> set("011010") == {"0", "1"}
True

>>> set("0110910") == {"0", "1"}
False
```

The test works even for empty string:

```
>>> set("")
set()
>>> set("") == {"0", "1"}
False
```

Comment: You'll need to use `<=` then as `'000'` is a valid string but won't result in the set `{'0', '1'}`. In which case you also need to test for length, so `s and set(s) <= {'0', '1'}` to be a complete test.

Comment: Yeah even I was using set to do this. Just wanted to know which one will be faster, the regex or this one. @MartijnPieters The number has to contain both 0 and 1 so 0000 will be invalid.

Comment: @Angersmash: ah, *that is important information*. Then you must use a set, actually.

Comment: @Angersmash: I've updated my answer to reflect this; sets can be used but regular expressions are way, way faster.

Comment: @Angersmash Using set solution is for shorter strings faster than using `re`, see my comments under answer of Martijn Pieters.